# Use JSX as view engine in Oak

Tags: jsx, deno, oak

I'm trying to create a simple html page with Deno and Oak.
As view engine I like to use JSX to generate the actual html.
Here is a simple example, but this fails because JSX is converted to React.createElement and React is not available.

But do I need to import the full React library now? Is that even possible?
(I don't need hooks)

```js
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v6.5.0/mod.ts";
import page from "./page.jsx";

const app = new Application();

app.use((ctx) => {
  ctx.response.body = page();
});

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

page.jsx

```js
export default function() {
    return(<div>TEST</div>)
}
```

Comment: well you would at least need something like the `renderToString` function https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it like this:

deps.ts

```js
export { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v6.5.0/mod.ts";
export { h } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/preact";
export { render } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/preact-render-to-string@v5.1.12";
```

home.jsx

```js
/** @jsx h */
import {h} from './deps.ts';

export default function () {
    return <div>TEST</div>
}
```

The JSX pragma is to replace React with h (hyperscript).
You can also use a tsconfig.json like below:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsxFactory": "h",
    }
}
```

You have to load it like this: `deno run --config ./tsconfig.json ...`

server.js

```js
import { Application, render } from "./deps.ts";
import home from "./home.jsx";

const app = new Application();

const respond = function (ctx, vdom) {
  ctx.response.type = "html";
  ctx.response.body = render(vdom(), {}, {pretty: true});
};

app.use((ctx) => {
  respond(ctx, home);
});

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

[Here](https://dev.to/r03/generate-html-on-the-server-with-deno-and-jsx-429b) is more information about using JSX in Deno.

Comment: yr blog is dead btw. I am trying to get this working aswell

Comment: I changed the url to the same article on dev.to. thanks.